# Android Volley - JsonArrayRequest returns null object

Tags: android, arrays, httprequest, android-volley

In the code below I am trying to send HttpRequest to my API to get locations which come as JSONArray. I am using Volley library and JsonArrayRequest. The problem is that when I set my local JSONArray variable in lambda I have proper value, but when I return it at the end of the function the object is null. I guess that the return is executed before the request is end, but I can be wrong.

```java
private RequestQueue requestQueue; //<----Global 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        //Initialization of RequestQueue Object
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
}

//Setting map settings, checking permissions etc..

private JSONArray getUsersLocation() {
        AtomicReference<JSONArray> result = new AtomicReference<>(new JSONArray());
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, API_URL + "getLocations", null, response -> {
                    result.set(response);
                   //Here I have correct value of result (JSONArray)
                    System.out.println(result.get()); 
                },
                        error -> {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot update users' location :" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
        return result.get(); //<----- Here my result is NULL
    }
```

I expect that the function getUsersLocation() will return JSONArray object which comes from the response.

Comment: Volley Http Requests are Asynchronous so, jsonArray return null  before the response will Come, so make your method void and intialize your List onSuccessListner after that your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

Http request in volley are Asynchronous, means that it doesn't block the execution, 
so in your code when you create the request, the return statement is executed before the request finishes so it returns null.
to fix this I segsst you use to create an interface and implement callbacks.
here is what you should do:

```
public interface HttpCallback {

     public void onSuccess(JSONArray array)

}
```

---

And modify your method to be:

```
private JSONArray getUsersLocation(HtttpCallback callback) {
    AtomicReference<JSONArray> result = new AtomicReference<>(new JSONArray());
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, API_URL + "getLocations", null, response -> {
                result.set(response);
               //Here I have correct value of result (JSONArray)
                System.out.println(result.get());
                callback.onSuccess(response):
            },
                    error -> {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot update users' location :" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, it is working perfectly the way I wanted ! I am using the Volley for the first time